Incompatible Android Gradle Plugin version in IntelliJ
In IntelliJ when doing a Gradle Sync I get error The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 8.4.1) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 8.2.0.
This same project opens correctly in Android Studio 2023.3.1.
I have IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1 withAndroid Plugin version 241.15989.150. No updates are available, neither for IDEA nor for the Android Plugin.
Is there any update that I'm missing? If not, I would like to know if it is to be expected that IntelliJ support for new versions of AGP lags behind Android Studio. Also I would like to know where can I find the compatibility tables for IntelliJ and AGP.

In my understanding this is due to the fact that Google develops Android Studio (yes it bases on IntelliJ platform but this is just the base) and the Gradle tools, but JetBrains maintains and develops the Android plugin for Intellij. So if Google releases an update to AS, JetBrain has to develop the necessary changes for the Android plugin.

I'm facing same issue...

There is an existing YouTrack Issue (IDEA-352815) for this.
